# How to subtract a number from initial value of a textbox when a certain item of combobox is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have textbox which I assign a value of 10 during UserForm Initialization.
I also have a comboBox that display 2 items; and another textbox that ask for a quantity(Number). I need to be able to subtract the quantity number from the initial value which is 10.

I tried the subtract function but nothing happen

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click()    
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range

    Set wks = Sheet1
    Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = cmbProduct.Value
    AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtQuantity.Text    
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    cmbProduct.Clear

    With cmbProduct
        .AddItem ("Chocolate")
        .AddItem ("Vanilla")
    End With

    txtChocolate.Text = 10
    txtVanilla.Text = 10 
End Sub
```

[image: Main UI Form]

Comment: You need to check the value of the dropdown list so you know if it's chocolate or vanilla and then check the quantity label. Then either `txtChocolate.Text = txtChocolate.Text - quantity lable` or vanilla one.

Comment: As widly known in mathematics the minus sign `-` is used for subtractions. This is possible in almost any programming language: `Result = A - B` will subtract `B` from `A` and write the result into `Result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
Private Sub txtQuantity_Change()
     If cmbProduct.Value = "chocolate" Then
        txtChocolate.Text = txtChocolate.Text - txtQuantity.Text
    ElseIf cmbProduct.Value = "Vanilla" Then
         txtVanilla.Text = txtVanilla.Text - txtQuantity.Text
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: This is not it, how do you know if it's vanilla or chocolate? You need to check first which one is.

Comment: Hi Luis Curado. I added the code you gave, and that performs the task, however when I click insert that gives me an error.Run-time error '13'
Type mismatch

Comment: Hi Luis Curado. Man you're amazing..that really helps a lot. Sir Damian thank you also for your assistance. I would like to ask another feature. I wanted to have an admin that would add the initial number of Vanilla and Ice Cream and then once he input the number it will locked out and no body can edit the textfield.

Comment: hi, and how u are thinking to get that admin ? if u want to use  the user that is logged in the pc, u can use the system variable  Environ("USERNAME")

Comment: @LuisCurado I am on the process of creating a simple Login for this project. My plan is to have an admin and a normal user for the system. The admin have the capability of adding the initial value for Chocolate and Vanilla and then once they input the value the textfield will then be locked so regular user cann't modify them..